# ASP.NET MVC - How to permanently redirect "action?id=5" style url's to "action/5"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a lot of controllers and actions in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application.

The default route config is:

```
routes.Add(
    new Route(
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new RouteValueDictionary(
            new {
                controller = "MyController",
                action = "Home",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        ),
        routeHandler: new MvcRouteHandler()
    )
);
```

Based on this default routing configuration, the actions (methods of controllers) are accessed in the following way:

http://example.com/controller/action/5

However they can also be accessed in the following way:

http://example.com/controller/action?id=5

which is bad for SEO (duplicate content).

Is there any general way to redirect (301) the second request (with query string) into the first one (the one without query strings)?

There are actions having multiple parameters with variable parameter names and I couldn't come up with an easy solution to this.

Comment: if its for SEO optimization then  you can use Canonical Url which will prevent duplicate indexing of your pages by search engines.

Comment: @Neel So you mean that I should add the following meta tag in each page:

`<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/controller/action/5" />`

Comment: well not on each page but if you add it on http://example.com/controller/action?id=5 pages it will serve the purpose of letting the search engines know - to not duplicate it as different content

Comment: I think it is reasonable enough, thanks! (_btw, I can neither upvote nor mark-as-answer your comment, sorry._)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its for SEO optimization then you can use Canonical Url which will prevent duplicate indexing of your pages by search engine
if you add it on example.com/controller/action?id=5 pages it will serve the purpose of letting the search engines know - to not duplicate it as different content

Comment: This will also help avoid costly redirects for these requests.